# how do I create a nested dictionary from a list based on file names?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a folder filled with files. I need to load these files and reconstruct a nested dictionary. The file names include the structure of the dictionary. For example, one file is called 'vz_ERA_Neural_Water_Forecast.npy'. 'vz' is the original dictionary name, 'ERA' is the first key, 'Neural' the second, and so on. Some files only nest 3 deep, some go 5 deep.

This is the code that I've tried:

```
# Get list of all the files to load
files = os.listdir(Path(fc.selected,'vz_save'))
# remove from list name of file that contains files we care about and hidden files
files.remove('fileNamesAndTypes.txt')
for file in files:
    if file.startswith('.'):
        files.remove(file)


# creat an empty dictionary in which to eventually allocate the loaded files
vz_check = {}

for file in files: 
    #print(file)
    ext = Path(file).suffix
    fileNoExt = Path(file).stem # remove the file extension (file type)
    keys = fileNoExt.split('_')
    keys.remove('vz')
        
    # find matching fileNoExt to value in fileNamesAndTypes[key]
    reloadedType = fileNamesAndTypes_check[fileNoExt]
        
        
    # load the file?
    if reloadedType == str:
        #print(f"type=str; reloadedType={reloadedType}")
        reload = open(Path(fc.selected,'vz_save',file),'rb')
        contents = reload.read()
        print(contents)
        for key in reversed(keys):
            vz_check = {key: vz_check}
    elif reloadedType == xr.core.dataset.Dataset:
        #print(f"type=xr.core.dataset.Dataset; reloadedType={reloadedType}")
    elif reloadedType == xr.core.dataarray.DataArray:
        #print(f"type=xr.core.dataarray.DataArray; reloadedType={reloadedType}")
    elif reloadedType == int:
        #print(f"type=int; reloadedType={reloadedType}")
    elif reloadedType == list:
        #print(f"type=list; reloadedType={reloadedType}")
    elif reloadedType == np.ndarray:
        #print(f"type=np.ndarray; reloadedType={reloadedType}")
```

What I end up getting is a pretty ugly super nesting with only a line of singular keys at each level going deeper and deeper, rather than multiple keys at each level.
[vz_check result screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqDmN.png)

The end result should be something like this:
[vz original screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrKWK.png)

How do I get this to automatically load and stitch all of the nested parts together. Is there a better way to go about this?

EDIT:

While waiting for help, I've come up with this solution that I feel is pretty friggin' ugly, but will get the job done. There has got to be a better way to do this.

```
def buildDict(keyss,contentss,theDict):
    if len(keyss) == 1:
        theDict = {keyss: contentss}
    elif len(keyss) == 2:
        theDict = {keyss[0] : { keyss[1] : contentss } }
    elif len(keyss) == 3: 
        theDict = {keyss[0] : {keyss[1] : {keyss[2] : contentss } } }
    elif len(keyss) == 4: 
        theDict = {keyss[0] : {keyss[1] : {keyss[2] : {keyss[3] : contentss } } } }
    elif len(keyss) == 5: 
        theDict = {keyss[0] : {keyss[1] : {keyss[2] : {keyss[3] : {keyss[4] : contentss } } } } }
```

Comment: [Please don't post pictures of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341); post the text itself.

Comment: More broadly, please make a [mre] including complete but minimal code (e.g. `fc` is not defined) and inputs (i.e. filenames and contents), along with the desired output and actual output that you currently have in the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution.

Since I know what the dictionary vz is supposed to look like, I just preset that as a structure and use this code below to fill in the blanks. Right now it only works for 'reloadedType == str', but the rest should be relatively easy to figure out. I'm sure there's a better way, but this works.

```
# load the individual files and reconstruct the dictionary
vz_reloaded = {
key1: {
    key2: {
        sub_key: [] for sub_key in [
            'Reof', 'Training_Data', 'Filetype', 'Polarization',
            'Coeffs', 'Modes', 'Models', 'Score', 'RMSE', 'Reof_forecast', 'Input_Images',
            'Reof_hindcast', 'Hindcast', 'Forecast', 'Best_Index', 'Difference',
            'Water_Hindcast', 'Water_Forecast'
        ]
    }
    for key2 in ['Polynomial', 'Neural']
}
for key1 in ['Q', 'ERA']
}

# Get list of all the files to load
files = os.listdir(Path(fc.selected,'vz_save'))
# remove from list name of file that contains files we care about and hidden files
files.remove('fileNamesAndTypes.txt')
for file in files:
    if file.startswith('.'):
        files.remove(file)

# creat an empty dictionary in which to eventually allocate the loaded files
vz_reloaded = {}

for file in files: 
    #print(file)
    ext = Path(file).suffix
    fileNoExt = Path(file).stem # remove the file extension (file type)
    keys = fileNoExt.split('_')
    keys.remove('vz')
        
    # find matching fileNoExt to value in fileNamesAndTypes[key]
    reloadedType = fileNamesAndTypes_check[fileNoExt]
        
        
    # load the file?
    if reloadedType == str:
        #print(f"type=str; reloadedType={reloadedType}")
        reload = open(Path(fc.selected,'vz_save',file),'rb')
        contents = reload.read()
    elif reloadedType == xr.core.dataset.Dataset:
        #print(f"type=xr.core.dataset.Dataset; reloadedType={reloadedType}")
        pass
    elif reloadedType == xr.core.dataarray.DataArray:
        #print(f"type=xr.core.dataarray.DataArray; reloadedType={reloadedType}")
        pass
    elif reloadedType == int:
        #print(f"type=int; reloadedType={reloadedType}")
        pass
    elif reloadedType == list:
        #print(f"type=list; reloadedType={reloadedType}")
        pass
    elif reloadedType == np.ndarray:
        #print(f"type=np.ndarray; reloadedType={reloadedType}")
        pass
    
    # Here's the part that puts the pieces of the dictionary back in. 
    try:
        if len(keys)==3:
            vz_reloaded[keys[0]][keys[1]][keys[2]] = contents
        elif len(keys)==4: 
            vz_reloaded[keys[0]][keys[1]][keys[2]][keys[3]] = contents
        elif len(keys)==5: 
            vz_reloaded[keys[0]][keys[1]][keys[2]][keys[3]][keys[4]] = contents
    except:
        print(f"This key set is a problem: {keys}")
        print(f"Type: {reloadedType}")
```